# ProGuard avoid obfuscation of interface implementations

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I have an anonymous class which implements an interface from another jar file (which is passed in as library jar).

```
//Some jar file
public interface B
{
  void methodA();
}

//My App
public class A implements B
{
  public void methodA()
  {
    //implementation here
  }
}
```

And its used in the app in the following manner:

```
B var = new A();
var.methodA();
```

After running into a bug (calling abstract method), I noticed ProGuard had renamed `methodA()` in class `A`. Note that there may be more instances of such wrong obfuscations.

- How do I stop proguard from renaming such interface implementations?
- Why is it renaming the method in the first place?

**EDIT:**
This is how I specify my library jars:

```
<libraryjar filter="!**\some.specific.jar,${base.dir}\dist\lib\*.jar" />
```

also tried:

```
<libraryjar jarfilter="!**\some.specific.jar" />
<libraryjar jarfilter="${base.dir}\dist\lib\*.jar" />
```

Neither worked. ProGuard doesn't read the library jars specified by the filter. It only reads the ones named explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGuard doesn't rename program methods that implement or override library methods -- hardly any processed application would work otherwise. You should double-check that your configuration really specifies the proper input jars and library jars. ProGuard may already be printing out warnings if something doesn't seem consistent.

Comment: You're right, I am getting warnings about that. I have specified my library jars using a filter which proguard apparently can't understand. Post updated.

Comment: You need to specify <libraryjar path=".....">. The filters are optional. See http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/ant.html

Comment: Yes I noticed that, somehow I thought when specifying filter I wouldn't need the path :S Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

To keep classes implementing interface B, just add something like this to your proguard configuration file:

```
-keep class ** implements B {
    *;
}
```

However, I notice that class A does not implement B correctly. The correct code for implementing B is

```
public class A implements B
{
  // note the public modifier
  public void methodA()
  {
    //implementation here
  }
}
```

That is why proguard renamed the method.

Comment: That was a typo. Also as mentioned already in the post, I'm not looking for a way to get rid of this occurrence only since there may be more of them that I'm currently not aware of.